# Infopath form content type column

Tags: infopath, content-type

I have a library with InfoPath as the content type.
I have many fields in my InfoPath form but all of these fields don't appear in my library view as columns.

Someone know how it work?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While publishing the InfoPath form you must also add and publish the form fields at Form Options screen. You need to publish the InfoPath fields then only it will show in SharePoint Library as columns.

[image]